# conference call like zoom in a flutter

Tags: flutter, conference, zoom-sdk, videocall

I want a conference video call in my app in flutter anyone has any idea about how to do that except agora as I know already about it but it's paid. so any other solution?

one more thing does zoom support in flutter?

Comment: Check this support for all platforms: https://developer.enablex.io/video-api/client-api/flutter-toolkit/

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/enx_flutter_plugin

Comment: @Daljeet it's one to one right?

Comment: Its one to one and one to many both. Its a plugin which you can use in your application.

Comment: okay thanks @Daljeet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes You Can Use `jitsi_meet` Package For this : Here is the Example :

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:jitsi_meet/feature_flag/feature_flag.dart';
import 'package:jitsi_meet/jitsi_meet.dart';
import 'package:jitsi_meet/jitsi_meeting_listener.dart';
import 'package:jitsi_meet/room_name_constraint.dart';
import 'package:jitsi_meet/room_name_constraint_type.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final serverText = TextEditingController();
  final roomText = TextEditingController(text: "plugintestroom");
  final subjectText = TextEditingController(text: "My Plugin Test Meeting");
  final nameText = TextEditingController(text: "Plugin Test User");
  final emailText = TextEditingController(text: "fake@email.com");
  var isAudioOnly = true;
  var isAudioMuted = true;
  var isVideoMuted = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    JitsiMeet.addListener(JitsiMeetingListener(
        onConferenceWillJoin: _onConferenceWillJoin,
        onConferenceJoined: _onConferenceJoined,
        onConferenceTerminated: _onConferenceTerminated,
        onPictureInPictureWillEnter: _onPictureInPictureWillEnter,
        onPictureInPictureTerminated: _onPictureInPictureTerminated,
        onError: _onError));
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    JitsiMeet.removeAllListeners();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Plugin example app'),
        ),
        body: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: 16.0,
          ),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(
                  height: 24.0,
                ),
                TextField(
                  controller: serverText,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                      labelText: "Server URL",
                      hintText: "Hint: Leave empty for meet.jitsi.si"),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 16.0,
                ),
                TextField(
                  controller: roomText,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    labelText: "Room",
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 16.0,
                ),
                TextField(
                  controller: subjectText,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    labelText: "Subject",
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 16.0,
                ),
                TextField(
                  controller: nameText,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    labelText: "Display Name",
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 16.0,
                ),
                TextField(
                  controller: emailText,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    labelText: "Email",
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 16.0,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 16.0,
                ),
                CheckboxListTile(
                  title: Text("Audio Only"),
                  value: isAudioOnly,
                  onChanged: _onAudioOnlyChanged,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 16.0,
                ),
                CheckboxListTile(
                  title: Text("Audio Muted"),
                  value: isAudioMuted,
                  onChanged: _onAudioMutedChanged,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 16.0,
                ),
                CheckboxListTile(
                  title: Text("Video Muted"),
                  value: isVideoMuted,
                  onChanged: _onVideoMutedChanged,
                ),
                Divider(
                  height: 48.0,
                  thickness: 2.0,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 64.0,
                  width: double.maxFinite,
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      _joinMeeting();
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      "Join Meeting",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                    color: Colors.blue,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 48.0,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  _onAudioOnlyChanged(bool value) {
    setState(() {
      isAudioOnly = value;
    });
  }

  _onAudioMutedChanged(bool value) {
    setState(() {
      isAudioMuted = value;
    });
  }

  _onVideoMutedChanged(bool value) {
    setState(() {
      isVideoMuted = value;
    });
  }

  _joinMeeting() async {
    String serverUrl =
        serverText.text?.trim()?.isEmpty ?? "" ? null : serverText.text;

    try {
      // Enable or disable any feature flag here
      // If feature flag are not provided, default values will be used
      // Full list of feature flags (and defaults) available in the README
      FeatureFlag featureFlag = FeatureFlag();
      featureFlag.welcomePageEnabled = false;
      // Here is an example, disabling features for each platform
      if (Platform.isAndroid) {
        // Disable ConnectionService usage on Android to avoid issues (see README)
        featureFlag.callIntegrationEnabled = false;
      } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
        // Disable PIP on iOS as it looks weird
        featureFlag.pipEnabled = false;
      }

      //uncomment to modify video resolution
      //featureFlag.resolution = FeatureFlagVideoResolution.MD_RESOLUTION;

      // Define meetings options here
      var options = JitsiMeetingOptions()
        ..room = roomText.text
        ..serverURL = serverUrl
        ..subject = subjectText.text
        ..userDisplayName = nameText.text
        ..userEmail = emailText.text
        ..audioOnly = isAudioOnly
        ..audioMuted = isAudioMuted
        ..videoMuted = isVideoMuted
        ..featureFlag = featureFlag;

      debugPrint("JitsiMeetingOptions: $options");
      await JitsiMeet.joinMeeting(
        options,
        listener: JitsiMeetingListener(onConferenceWillJoin: ({message}) {
          debugPrint("${options.room} will join with message: $message");
        }, onConferenceJoined: ({message}) {
          debugPrint("${options.room} joined with message: $message");
        }, onConferenceTerminated: ({message}) {
          debugPrint("${options.room} terminated with message: $message");
        }, onPictureInPictureWillEnter: ({message}) {
          debugPrint("${options.room} entered PIP mode with message: $message");
        }, onPictureInPictureTerminated: ({message}) {
          debugPrint("${options.room} exited PIP mode with message: $message");
        }),
        // by default, plugin default constraints are used
        //roomNameConstraints: new Map(), // to disable all constraints
        //roomNameConstraints: customContraints, // to use your own constraint(s)
      );
    } catch (error) {
      debugPrint("error: $error");
    }
  }

  static final Map<RoomNameConstraintType, RoomNameConstraint>
      customContraints = {
    RoomNameConstraintType.MAX_LENGTH: new RoomNameConstraint((value) {
      return value.trim().length <= 50;
    }, "Maximum room name length should be 30."),
    RoomNameConstraintType.FORBIDDEN_CHARS: new RoomNameConstraint((value) {
      return RegExp(r"[$€£]+", caseSensitive: false, multiLine: false)
              .hasMatch(value) ==
          false;
    }, "Currencies characters aren't allowed in room names."),
  };

  void _onConferenceWillJoin({message}) {
    debugPrint("_onConferenceWillJoin broadcasted with message: $message");
  }

  void _onConferenceJoined({message}) {
    debugPrint("_onConferenceJoined broadcasted with message: $message");
  }

  void _onConferenceTerminated({message}) {
    debugPrint("_onConferenceTerminated broadcasted with message: $message");
  }

  void _onPictureInPictureWillEnter({message}) {
    debugPrint("_onPictureInPictureWillEnter broadcasted with message: $message");
  }

  void _onPictureInPictureTerminated({message}) {
    debugPrint("_onPictureInPictureTerminated broadcasted with message: $message");
  }

  _onError(error) {
    debugPrint("_onError broadcasted: $error");
  }
}
```